# Is there a way for mapping object to relational database via MyBatis at runtime?

Tags: java, orm, mybatis, persistent

I create Java classes and  their instances at runtime (Java Compiler API) and I want to map them to a database with the help of MyBatis API also when program running. Is there some way to do this in MyBatis?

It's really important and any help with this will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You basically want to intervene on the running context of a framework, modify it and keep the context consistent enough for the framework to run correctly. All that considering that MyBatis was not designed for it.

The answer [may be YES](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13195144/can-i-use-mybatis-to-generate-dynamic-sql-without-executing-it/) or may be NO, but I'm afraid that **the only way to find out is to try it**.

Don't know what you are doing but before tinkering with MyBatis maybe you should think if it won't be less of an effort to implement something custom for what seems to be specific behavior (MyBatis is a general purpose framework).

Just my 2 cents!