# BoundSql does not substitute values of parameter in SQL statement in MyBatis

Tags: java, mysql, spring, mybatis

I need to print generated SQL in MyBatis but without executing it. I have tried procedure from topic: [Can I use MyBatis to generate Dynamic SQL without executing it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13195144/can-i-use-mybatis-to-generate-dynamic-sql-without-executing-it). It works except for one thing. There are '?' symbols instead of data in printed SQL. So it looks just like this:

```
insert into testTable (name, data) values (?,?)
```

Here is the code I am using:

Pojo

```
public class TestPojo {
  Integer id;
  String name;
  String data;
  //Ommitted getters and setters
}
```

DAO

```
public interface TestDAO {
   public void insertData(TestPojo p);
}
```

Mapper.xml

```
<mapper namespace="package.TestDAO">

<resultMap id="testResult" type="TestPojo" >
    <id column="id" property="id" jdbcType="INTEGER"/>
    <result column="name" property="name" jdbcType="VARCHAR"/>
    <result column="data" property="data" jdbcType="VARCHAR"/>
</resultMap> 

<insert id="insertData" parameterType="TestPojo">
    insert into testTable (name, data) values (#{name},#{data})
</insert>

</mapper>
```

MyBatis config xml

```
<configuration>
<!--misc settings -->
<settings>
    <setting name="lazyLoadingEnabled" value="false" /> 
</settings>

<typeAliases>
    <typeAlias type="package.TestPojo" alias="TestPojo" />
</typeAliases>
<!--XML mappers -->    
<mappers>
    <mapper resource="database/TestMapper.xml" />
</mappers>
</configuration>
```

And finally I get SQL by using following code:

```
Configuration configuration = sqlSessionFactory.getConfiguration();
MappedStatement ms = configuration.getMappedStatement("insertData");
BoundSql boundSql = ms.getBoundSql(new TestPojo("Jeff", "The funny guy"));
System.out.println("SQL: \n" + boundSql.getSql());
```

What I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, still don't know why it doesn't work. So I've written simple method which will do the job.

```
public void createSQLReportItem(MappedStatement ms) {
    BoundSql boundSql = ms.getBoundSql(originalRec);
    List<ParameterMapping> params = boundSql.getParameterMappings();

    finalSql = boundSql.getSql();
    finalSql = finalSql.replaceAll("\\s", " ");
    finalSql = finalSql.replaceAll("[ ]{2,}", " ");

    for (ParameterMapping pm : params) {
        if (paramMapping.containsKey(pm.getProperty())) {
            finalSql = finalSql.replaceFirst("\\?", paramMapping.get(pm.getProperty()));
        }
    }
}
```

where `originalRec` is parameter for the statement and `paramMapping` is my own map containg mappings - param_name -> value. I know that it is not the best solution, but it works..